# How to uninstall cabal, cabal-nirvana and yesod

Tags: uninstallation, cabal, yesod

I am trying to find a way to remove cabal/cabal-nirvana/yesod from my system, I did install cabal with

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
```

second I would like to remove cabal-nirvana which I installed with

```
cabal install cabal-nirvana
```

and finally remove yesod for which I used the command

```
cabal install yesod-platform
```

Currently I have seen to exist a **/home/username/.cabal** folder, I just want to have my machine as close to previous state as possible (before trying to install yesod), this means removing all these things installed.

There is a lot of information on the web about insallation, however this seems not to be true for the uninstallation process.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove 'package-name'
```

This should remove the package along with all the fluff, I'm presuming you're using a Debian-based system.

Comment: I am under xubuntu and soon under debian too, "sudo apt-get --purge remove yesod" worked, as for cabal my mistake was that I used "apt...remove..cabal" instead of "apt...remove..cabal-install", now it is removed.

Comment: @Melsi You should make that an answer to fully comply with site guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I am under xubuntu, "sudo apt-get --purge remove yesod" worked for removing yesod, as for cabal my mistake was that I used "cabal" instead of "cabal-install", so it would be

"apt-get remove cabal-install", now it is removed.